# Finding matches in a dictionary

Tags: regex, trie

Question I've stumbled across recently and wanted to confirm if I came up with the ideal algorithm:
I need to design a class that essentially contains a dictionary of words, and then a method that determines if a pattern matches one or more words in that dictionary. The pattern is basically a dumbed down version of regex, with support only for "." character.
The class will have two methods:
void PreProcess(string[] words)
bool IsMatch(string word)

Examples: PreProcess(new string[] { "abc" }), then calling IsMatch("a.c") would return true.
My solution is roughly described below.
I ended up using a Trie. I built the Trie during the PreProcess method, and then in the IsMatch I traverse the trie. When I encounter a dot, I simply recursively iterate all the children of the current node to check if there are any matches.

My question is, what is the time complexity of this algorithm, and is there a better/more efficient solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm can be exponentially difficult if there are multiple dots in the regex. I once thought very hard how KMP could be generalized to a key with dots or even '*' (which represents an arbitrary number of arbitrary chars). But it seems KMP simply doesn't work, because both '.' and '*' will break the transitivity of char matching, meaning that unequal chars at different places of a string can be match the same '.' or '*' in the key. This completely throws the theory of KMP out of the window. If KMP doesn't work, I don't see how a trie can work.

An algorithm that surely works is trying to match the words in the dictionary with the key (regex) one by one. When there's a '.' in the key, just skip and see if the next char matches. This algorithm looks bad, but at least it will never be exponentially hard in the number of dots in the key. Avoid the worst case if you cannot hope to achieve the best case.

Comment: I disagree. If I'm not mistaken, OP's algorithm is between `O(log M)` in the best case (`abc`) and `O(M)` in the worst case (`...`), where `N` is the number of entries, and `M < N` is number of entries of length equal or less to the pattern length; meanwhile, your algorithm is always `O(N)` (worse). OP's algorithm *looks* exponential, but it is limited by the structure of the trie (all non-matching branches get pruned, and you can't ever get exponentialized into the `N^2` or worse territory simply because there aren't `N^2` nodes to examine, and each node gets examined only at most once.

Comment: So maybe an improved algorithm would be that the dictionary is still constructed as a trie, but only used as a tree (the back-jumping arrows of a trie wouldn't work for the '.' case). Then do a depth-first search (DFS) of the dictionary tree and record all words that match the regex. If the back-jumping arrows of a trie are still trusted, the algorithm might fail.

Comment: When I say DFS I mean the backtracking algorithm, not a DFS of all words. For example, when the regex to be found is "a.c", then any word that does not begin with an 'a' need not be searched. When there's a '.', all branches must be explored one by one. That's why we need backtracking.

Comment: As for the time complexity, the worst case is O(size of dictionary), because if all words in the dictionary are equally long, and your regex is all dots of that length, then all words must be found by a correct algorithm. The average case is better but hard to define.

Comment: Yes, I should have said `M <= N`. There is nothing about the definition of a trie that makes it have "back-jumping arrows" (or in fact anything in the definition of a tree that would prevent them). In fact, a trie is just a certain usage of a tree (specifically, a prefix tree).